# How can get second item of array with x-ray

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, x-ray

I want to get the second item in the `game:  ['.contenedor-numero'],` array :

```js
  var site = 'http://www.laliga.es/en/';
  var url = 'liga-bbva';
  var address = site + url;
  x(address, '#div_clasf_38_1_3 table tbody tr', [{
      rank: ".posicion",
      game:  ['.contenedor-numero'],
      score: ".contenedor-numero.puntos",
      name: x(".contenedor-nombre a", {
          Abbreviation: '.nombre-equipo-clasificacion-movil',
          complete: '.nombre-equipo-clasificacion'
      }),

  }])(function(err, data) {
      console.log(data);
  });
```

the html code struct is this :

```html
<tr class=" ">
    <td class="posicion">1</td>
    <td class="contenedor-flecha"></td>
    <td class="contenedor-nombre">
        <a href="http://www.laliga.es/en/liga-bbva/barcelona">
            <span class="escudo-equipo-clasificacion">
                            <span class="sprite-escudos-xs barcelona"></span>
            </span>
            <span class="nombre-equipo-clasificacion">FC Barcelona</span>
            <span class="nombre-equipo-clasificacion-movil">FCB</span>
        </a>
    </td>
    <td class="contenedor-numero puntos">91</td>
    <td class="contenedor-numero ">38</td>
    <td class="contenedor-numero no-sidebar">29</td>
    <td class="contenedor-numero no-sidebar">4</td>
    <td class="contenedor-numero no-sidebar">5</td>
    <td class="contenedor-numero no-sidebar">112</td>
    <td class="contenedor-numero no-sidebar">29</td>
</tr>
```

I want to scraping `<td>` elements that has `class="contenedor-numero "` with value of 38. But when I use `['.contenedor-numero'][1]` nothing give me!

How can I get second element of that array?

Comment: `Item` or `DOM Element`  ?

Comment: Have you tried document.getElementsByClassName(yourclass)[1].innerText

Answer (score 0):

you could do this:

```
  x(html2, 'tr', [{
      rank: ".posicion",
      game:  ['.contenedor-numero'],
      score: ".contenedor-numero.puntos",
      name: x(".contenedor-nombre a", {
          Abbreviation: '.nombre-equipo-clasificacion-movil',
          complete: '.nombre-equipo-clasificacion'
      }),
      value38: 'td:nth-of-type(5)'

  }])(function(err, data) {
      console.log(data);
  });
```